# Customizing the UI of Chronograf

Tags: chronograf

I am trying to use Chronograf in my project. I would like to change the UI of the Chronograf to suit the project.

I couldn't find any documents related to this. Can we customize the Chronograf UI to suit the requirement? If so, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

I did some similar work. I had to make sure the Chronograf UI was limited to the explore and dashboard tabs. Plus, I had to add user management so that users where limited to specific measurements and dashboards.

Chronograf is open source. You can clone it from https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf

- The back-end is written in Go.
- The UI is written in React.js (using
  Typescript).

You can find the UI code in the sub folder `/ui`: https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/tree/master/ui

To build it, you will need [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) and [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install).

If you only want to work on the UI, you can can edit `parcel.js` and change the location of `http://localhost:8888` to the location of your current Chronograf instance.

Then run `yarn start` from the `/ui` folder and go to http://localhost:8080

If you make changes to the UI code, http://localhost:8080 will automaticlly refresh to reflect your changes.

If you are ready with development, follow the instructions to build Chronograf from source in their Readme: https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf#from-source